# How can I remove a commit name instead of deleting it in local machine

Tags: git, git-commit

I have committed a piece of code as `commit1` but after finishing it, I want to remove the `commit1` and commit the entire code as `Initial Commit`.

When I run `git reset HEAD~` in Git Bash, it results in deleting all my code.

Is it possible to delete `commit1` instead of everything, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can for example run:

```
git rebase --interactive --root
```

And then change the action before the commit you want to squash to `f` (it stands for fixup = squash the commit to the previous one and discard the commit message). Then simply save and close the file (using `:wq` if it opened the default Vim editor).